# Associated graded of double Koszul dual

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be a graded, connected, augmented, locally finite $k$-algebra.  If $\Omega^* A$ denotes the cobar complex of $A$ (i.e., the dual $Hom_k(B_*(A), k)$ of the bar complex of $A$), then the cohomology $H^* \Omega^* A = Ext^{*, *}_A(k, k)$ computes the $Ext$ algebra of $A$.  This is bigraded; the first index is the $Ext$ degree, the second the internal degree via the cobar complex.

Derived Koszul duality gives a quasi-isomorphism between the double dual $\Omega^* \Omega^* A$ and $A$. Filtering this double complex by rows or columns, we get a spectral sequence whose $E_2$-term may be identified as

$$Ext_E(k, k) \implies A$$

where $E=Ext^{*, *}_A(k, k)$ (there are at least three gradings on the $E_2$ term of this spectral sequence; I will choose to suppress them all).

I believe that the finiteness assumptions that I have made at the start of this question ensure that the spectral sequence converges, so the $E_\infty$ term is the bigraded (maybe trigraded?) ring associated to a filtration on $A$.

**My question is:** what is this filtration?  Does it (and its associated graded ring) have an easy description?  I'm tempted to believe that it's the filtration by powers of the augmentation ideal, but have no real evidence for that other than wishful thinking.